# Django - issue with loading css

Tags: python, html, css, django

I've recently started learning Django and I've been having a lot of issues with implementing css into my code. I've found a lot of people with the same issue as me but I am still unable to find an answer.

Currently when I run open the website it give me this https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL1I3.jpg

And I'm not sure if this is because of the settings, the actual css or something in the html.

**My html boilerplate**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>homepage</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="test/css" href="{% static'css/home.css' %}"/>
</head>
```

**settings.py**

```
DEBUG = True
STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost']

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from leatherbiscuit.views import index

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns+=static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

    
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def home_view(request):
return HttpResponse(request, 'index.html')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a space between the name of the template tag and its parameters, so it should be:

```
         ↓ a space between static and 'css/home.css'
{% static 'css/home.css' %}
```

The parser of the Django template engine has some peculiarities. For example, a tag should not be spanned over multiple lines, and like in Python's method calls one should first list the positional parameters and then the named parameters.